# change color of sidebar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to change the background color of the sidebar of [this React app](http://lbd-react.creative-tim.com/#/dashboard). This is the [source code of the sidebar component](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react/blob/master/src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx). I tried removing the `data-color` attribute of this element

```
  <div
    id="sidebar"
    className="sidebar"
    data-color="black"
    data-image={imagine}>
```

and adding a CSS rule:

```
#sidebar {
  background-color: #0b7c9c !important;
}
```

But for some reason, the sidebar still has a black background. I'm pretty sure the background color is being set via JavaScript in a manner that overrides all CSS rules, but I can't figure out how/where.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the css for the class `sidebar`? I.e `.sidebar { background-color: 0}`

Comment: Isn't the property `backgroundColor`? I hope it is not `background-color`

Comment: @Rama it is indeed `background-color`. What's the problem? Kebab casing is consistent with being able to use `background` to set all the `background-*` properties.

Comment: @DmitryNarkevich My bad. I thought he was using React Native.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the background color is coming from `:before` pseudo-element of `sidebar` class, so you need to use `!important` to `.sidebar:before` background.

```
.sidebar:before, body>.navbar-collapse:before {
    opacity: .33;
    background: #f00 !important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the `.sidebar-background` might be causing issues.

```
.sidebar {
  background: #0b7c9c !important;
}

.sidebar-background {
  display: none;
}
```